# Subclassing QIODevice by overriding non-virtual methods

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, virtual-functions

I would like to subclass from QIODevice since I'm creating my custom device (a custom serial port object).

I see that:

```
writeData(const char *, qint64 ) : qint64
readData(char *, qint64 ) : qint64
```

are declared as virtual in QIODevice interface, but not the methods:

```
read(char *, qint64 ) : qint64
write(const char *, qint64 ) : qint64
```

Then in my project I have a serial port manager class like this:

```
class SerialPortManager{
public:
    SerialPortManager(int type){
         if (type == 1)
             genericSerialPort = new QSerialPort(); //QT framework
         else if (type == 2)
             genericSerialPort = new MySerialPort(); //my custom object, derived from QIODevice
    }

    qint64 write(char * data, qint64 size)
    {
        genericSerialPort->write(data, size);
    }    

private:
    QIODevice* genericSerialPort = 0;
};
```

And my custom serial port (MySerialPort.h) defined like this:

```
class MySerialPort : public QIODevice{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MySerialPort(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        virtual ~MySerialPort();

        qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxSize);
        qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 maxSize);

        qint64 write(char * data, qint64 size);

        ...
    };
```

What's happening here is that if I create a `SerialPortManager` object of type 1 (`QSerialPort` instance) and I call `write` on it, the `write` function on `QSerialPort` is called.
Instead, if I create a `SerialPortManager` object of type 2 (`MySerialPort` instance) and I call `write` on it, I don't get my `write` function called.

So, is it possible to override the non-virtual method `write` of `QIODevice`?
Otherwise, how can I create a custom `QIODevice` if `write` and `read` are not virtual?

Comment: You cannot override non-virtual methods, you can only shadow them, which is not going to help. You have to override write_data, not write (which you cannot do).

Comment: @n.m. suppose I override just writeData method. What happen if I call write on my object? Is my writeData implementation called if the base class call it on its write method?

Comment: it is documented that way. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#details

Comment: "Is my writeData implementation called if the base class call it on its write method?" Yes, that's the point of writeData being virtual.

Comment: You will go nowhere without a debug build of Qt. Once you have it, use it to trace what's happening when you call 'QIODevice::read' or 'write'. Then you'll understand. Really.

Comment: @KubaOber: good point

Comment: I've solved the case by adding in subclassed method `bool open(OpenMode mode)` the line `QIODevice::open(mode);` otherwise the `QIODevice::write` does not call my `writeData` implementation because think that the device has not been opened. if it were written in the doc it would have helped me.

Comment: @ABCplus Do you need to override that method? You can just open the base `QIODevice` and that should do.

Comment: @KubaOber: I overridden that method to implement my custom open. The base `QIODevice::open` call was just done to make the link from `QIODevice::write` to my `MySerialPort::writeData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by design. If write and read are not virtual they are not meant to be overridden.

`readData` and `writeData` are pure virtual and protected. So I would assume `write` and `read` will call these internally.

As to why they are not overridable you have to ask the Qt Designers. It is most likely they modify some internal states etc. which are private so it has to be wrapped in those calls.

Usually Qt classes are pretty well designed so I assume you should not need to override `write` and `read` in the first place. If you do there maybe some issue with your design.

Comment: Ok, but if I call read or write methods on my object the overridden writeData and readData are not called.

Comment: General speaking, if I call read on my class then the read of base class is called right? Then, on its implementation suppose it calls the virtual readData. Is it called the readData of based or derived?

Comment: have you opened the device and in the read/write mode? You probably run into an error before you actually get to the writeing/reading. Check the return value of write/read and check the error with `errorString()`

Comment: you should not have a `read` function in your class. So it only has the base class function. `QIODevice` has no `readData` on it's own (it's pure virtual) so yours will be called then. But by basic OO principles the derived one will be called.

Comment: If you are unsure when what functions will be called with virtual and overriding them I guess it's best to write some small program (no qt just some classes) and try it out yourself. This can help understanding how this works.